# sourcemap-explorer shows extra bits and pieces from @ng-bootstrap

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have been playing around with a tool called sourcemap-explorer, and I noticed that even when I import only `NgbDateParserFormatter` and `NgbDatepickerModule` from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, sourcemap-explorer shows that I am getting accordion, carousel, tabset, popover, tooltip, etc. I thought the idea of importing an individual module was to avoid grabbing the whole package. Has anyone else run into this?

**Edit 1:**
This is what I'm importing:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDatepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

This is where I use it:

```
<input class="form-control" 
    placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" 
    formControlName="effectiveDate"
    ngbDatepicker 
    #sd="ngbDatepicker">
<div class="input-group-addon" (click)="sd.toggle()">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you import / use and package things exactly? Hard to say anything meaningful based just on the info provided...

Comment: Edited to show what I'm importing and where it is being used. If need be, I can throw in the custom parser-formatter I wrote, but I promise I don't ask for modals and carousels in it. lol. I am using @angular/cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the packager / bundler you use, you might end up with more code then needed if you import from the catch-all module path (`@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`).

To bump up your chances of getting only used code (the final result *will* depend on the bundler used) try importing from a datepicker-specific module path: `import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDatepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.module';`

The above should work just fine with angular-cli.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but the result is the same. I understand using something like rollup might shake those parts out. I just don't see where they are being imported in the first place.

Comment: @wolfhoundjesse could you please prepare a _minimal_ CLI project, share it somewhere on GitHub and open an issue in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues? It is hard to say more without a reproduce scenario, especially that I've tested it some time ago and was able to import individual components only.

Comment: Score! While producing a repo for you, everything worked perfectly. I went back to triple check my work, and I found a single component importing from `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` instead of `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker.module`. I also updated the path in your answer to reflect the extra *ng-bootstrap*.